# How to get the public ip and port to connect over the internet

Tags: c#, networking

So I'm not much of a network developer when it comes to the actual connecting part. At the moment I can connect peer to peer using a master server to relay ips/ports.

What i want to do now, is cut out the master server by displaying to the user thier public ip and port, so they can just message their friend saying hey, connect to this ip/port.

I've been looking around and the public ip part seems easy enough, just send a http request to a website and parse the response, cool. But how do I go about finding the port?

Using c# by the way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using public IPs is not very secure.
2. Lots of users don't have public IP, they are behind of NAT
3. You really can't open port to the internet, because of the firewall and NAT as I mentioned before.
4. You can try to find some PTP solution (I think WebRTC works somehow this way, but I really don't know much about it)

Answer (score 0):

I would use STUN. This will establish a temporary NAT Mapping that will allow users to send traffic back the program that created the mapping. NAT Traversal is mostly done with UDP, it is possible with TCP but I haven't ever seen it used in production myself.

I don't have a C# example, but [stun-nat-behavior](https://github.com/pion/stun/tree/master/cmd/stun-nat-behaviour) is a CLI program that prints details about the NAT.

One important thing to note is that behaviors between NATs can be very different. So this will not work in all networks. Some NATs don't allow mapping at all, some NATs allow mapping but only one remote peer can use it. I wrote about this more in depth with [WebRTC for the Curious - Networking](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/#nat-mapping)

Some gateways also provide the [Port Control Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_Control_Protocol). Instead of depending on a STUN server and dealing with network hardware differences this gives you a single API. This isn't as widely available however.